# Continuous redirections in .htacess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How to get rid of the error that causes continuous redirection? I would like these rules to work in both directions.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/([a-z0-9-]+)/$ search.php?name=$1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^search\.php$ https://example.com/search/%1/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: have you tried to add the last flag [L] in your first rule ?

Comment: Yes, i added and this is the same

Answer (score 0):

there's a redirection loop 
you may use an environnement variable to check if your url is in a Redirection context

```
 # redirect pretty url to real php
 RewriteRule ^search/([a-z0-9-]+)/$ search.php?name=$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.*)$
 # force pretty url with 301 unless in a rewrite 
 RewriteRule ^search\.php$ https://example.com/search/%1/? [L,R=301]
```